# Load a static txt file and a dynamic txt file into a div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've got two txt files on my server.
File 1 is the static one which contains the first part of an html file (https://lodysreizen.nl/beh/htmlbegin.text).

File 2 is the dynamic file which contains the second part of the html file (https://lodysreizen.nl/verslag.text).

Currently I use the function below to put the dynamic html info into a div and process it. I've found out that I needed the beginning (which is in the static txt file) also.

How can I load both txt file in such a way that the information gets processed as one html?

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#middiv").load("verslag.text");
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Can't you use two elements to load instead of just one? Seems like simplest approach

Comment: Presumably since you have tagged your question with `php`, you also know how to use it, so why not just use `<?php include('verslag.txt') ?>`? This task seems like it would better suit inclusion using PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code.

```
$.post("verslag.text",  function(res, status) {
  $("#middiv").html(res);
});
```

Comment: A POST to a static text file doesn't make much sense